# How to check if point is a vertex of a set

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

Consider the set $K=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^4: Ax=a,~x_i\geq  0\}$
with
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&-1&2\\ \:\:\:\:0&1&0&3\\ \:\:\:\:2&0&-2&10\end{pmatrix}\quad a=\begin{pmatrix}2\\ 7\\ 18\end{pmatrix}$$
Which of the vectors is a vertex of the set?

$$x_1=\begin{pmatrix}10\\ \:7\\ \:0\\ \:0\end{pmatrix},~x_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ \:\:1\\ \:\:1\\ \:\:2\end{pmatrix},~x_3=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ \:\:\:1\\ \:\:\:2\\ \:\:\:2\end{pmatrix},~ x_4=\begin{pmatrix}9\\ \:\:\:7\\ \:\:\:\:0\\ \:\:\:\:0\end{pmatrix}$$

So I checked that 
$Ax_2=a$, $Ax_3=a$ and $Ax_4=a$. But $Ax_1=\begin{pmatrix}3\\ 7\\ 20\end{pmatrix}$ so $x_1$ is not in $K$. How do I check if the other points are vertices?

Vertex;
$$G\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n~\text{convex}, z\in  G ~\text{vertex} \iff~x,y\in G: z=\frac{x+y}{2} \Rightarrow x=y=z$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with the way the word vertex is being used here can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes sure ill add it to the body of the question

Comment: Hint: A vertex of a polyhedron in the form $Ax \geq b$ is a point $v$ such that there is a set of $n$ linearly independent inequalities which are saturated (i.e. satisfied with equality). Augment your $A$ with the inequalities $x_i \geq 0$, and see what happens when you plug in $x_2, x_3, x_4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider the vector $x_2$ . . .

Let's attempt to represent $x_2$ as the midpoint of two distinct points of $K$.

Thus, suppose $x_2\pm v\in K$, for some nonzero $v\in\mathbb{R}^4$.

Equivalently, $v\in\mathbb{R}^4$ is such that
$$
\begin{cases}
Av=0\\[4pt]
x_2\pm v \ge 0\\
\end{cases}
$$
Since $x_2[1]=0$, the conditions $x_2\pm v \ge 0$ force $v[1]=0$, hence
$$v=\begin{pmatrix}0\\q\\r\\s\end{pmatrix}$$
for some $q,r,s\in\mathbb{R}$, not all zero.

Expressing the condition $Av=0$ as a system of equations, we get
$$
\begin{cases}
q+3s=0\\[4pt]
 -q-r+2s=0\\[4pt]
-r+5s = 0\\[4pt]
\end{cases}
$$
which has the general solution
\begin{cases}
q=-3s=0\\[4pt]
r=5s
\end{cases}
where $s\in\mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary.

If $s$ is sufficiently small, but not zero (e.g., $s={\large{\frac{1}{10}}}$), we get $x_2\pm v\ge 0$.

It follows that $x_2$ is not a vertex of $K$.

Next, consider the vector $x_3$ . . .

Let's attempt to represent $x_3$ as the midpoint of two distinct points of $K$.

Thus, suppose $x_3\pm v\in K$, for some nonzero $v\in\mathbb{R}^4$.

Equivalently, $v\in\mathbb{R}^4$ is such that
$$
\begin{cases}
Av=0\\[4pt]
x_3\pm v \ge 0\\
\end{cases}
$$
Write
$$v=\begin{pmatrix}p\\q\\r\\s\end{pmatrix}$$
for some $p,q,r,s\in\mathbb{R}$, not all zero.

Expressing the condition $Av=0$ as a system of equations, we get
$$
\begin{cases}
p-q-r+2s= 0\\[4pt]
p-r+5s=0\\[4pt]
q+3s=0\\
\end{cases}
$$
which has the general solution
\begin{cases}
r=p+5s\\[4pt]
q=-3s\\[4pt]
\end{cases}
where $p,s\in\mathbb{R}$ are arbitrary.

If $p,s$ are sufficiently small, and $s,p+5s$ are not both zero (e.g., $p=s={\large{\frac{1}{10}}}$), we get $x_3\pm v\ge 0$.

It follows that $x_3$ is not a vertex of $K$.

Finally, consider the vector $x_4$ . . .

Let's attempt to represent $x_4$ as the midpoint of two distinct points of $K$.

Thus, suppose $x_4\pm v\in K$, for some nonzero $v\in\mathbb{R}^4$.

Equivalently, $v\in\mathbb{R}^4$ is such that
$$
\begin{cases}
Av=0\\[4pt]
x_4\pm v \ge 0\\
\end{cases}
$$
Since $x_4[3]=x_4[4]=0$, the conditions $x_4\pm v \ge 0$ force $v[3]=v[4]=0$, hence
$$v=\begin{pmatrix}p\\q\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
for some $p,q\in\mathbb{R}$, not both zero.

Expressing the condition $Av=0$ as a system of equations, we get
$$
\begin{cases}
q=0\\[4pt]
p-q=0\\[4pt]
p= 0\\
\end{cases}
$$
which has no solutions other than $p=q=0$.

It follows that $x_4$ is a vertex of $K$.

Comment: If s is sufficiently small, but not zero (e.g.,$ s=1/10$), we get $x_2±v≥0$.

It follows that $x_2$ is not a vertex of $K$. I dont understand why it follows

Comment: Just plug in $s=1/10$ into $v$, and actually evaluate $x2\pm v$. Alternatively, if $s$ is close to zero, then $x2\pm v$ is close to $x_2$, hence all components are nonnegative (since we forced the first component of $v$ to be zero).